# General Principles of Solving Radical Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

What are the general ways to solve radical equations similar to questions like

> $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x^2 -1}=x$
>  
>  $\sqrt{3x-1}+\sqrt{5x-3}+\sqrt{x-1}=2\sqrt2$
> $\sqrt{\frac{4x+1}{x+3}}-\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x+3}}=1$

Are there just a few known ways to solve them? How do you know the best way to solve such questions? I have trouble with a lot of square root equations, and when I ask them on this site, I get good answers, but for one question. I was wondering if there were any general principles of solving such questions.

Comment: The most basic is to isolate one of the square roots, square both sides, and this eill usually yield less square roots than when you started with. Keep repeating until you have no more square roots. This works pretty well in most cases, but as you can see by Dr. Graubner's answer, there are sometimes some tricks, arising from the particular problems themselves ways, which allow you to solve the equations much faster

Comment: [Example question (with answers on how to approach it)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785728)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One rather general strategy is to replace each new root $\sqrt[k]{expression}$ in the equation by a new variable, $r_j$, together with a new equation 
$r_j^k = expression$ (so now you will have $m+1$ polynomial equations in $m+1$ unknowns, where $m$ is the number of roots).  Then eliminate variables from the system, ending with a single polynomial equation in one unknown, such that your original variable can be expressed in terms of the roots of this polynomial.  This procedure can introduce spurious solutions if you only want the principal branch of the $k$'th root, so don't forget to check whether the solutions you get are valid.

For example, in your second equation,
we get the system
$$ \eqalign{r_1 + r_2 + r_3 - 2 \sqrt{2} &= 0\cr
 r_1^2-(3x-1) &= 0\cr r_2^2-(5x-3) &= 0\cr
r_3^2-(x-1) &=0\cr}$$
Take the resultant of the first two polynomials with respect to $r_1$, then the resultant of this and the third with respect to $r_2$, and the resultant of this and the fourth with respect to $r_3$.  We get
$$ 121 x^4-4820 x^3+28646 x^2-45364 x+21417$$
which happens to factor as
$$ \left( x-1 \right)  \left( x-33 \right)  \left( 121\,{x}^{2}-706\,x+
649 \right) 
$$
However, only the solution $x=1$ turns out to satisfy the original equation.

Comment: also with your method we have to solve a polynomial, can you factorize this thing by hand?

Comment: I confess that I did not do this by hand, though in principle the Rational Roots Theorem might be helpful to one trying such a foolish thing.

Comment: and if it is not helpful? you must also use a numerical method, these equations have not a general form

Comment: No, you use a Computer Algebra system.

Comment: such a system makes also mistakes, a computer can prove nothing

Comment: Humans also make mistakes.  Computers can and do prove things.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sometimes they do. But they shouldn't unless we ask them too. Otherwise, its considered rude :)

Comment: So I pretty much have to use a calculator right.

Comment: Most calculators would not be terribly useful for this.

Comment: @RobertIsrael.- Could you please explain me what is meant by " taking the resultant" of two polynomials? Does it amount to " adding" them? Thanks.

Comment: This is a great answer. Is it your own finding, or is there a good source explaining this method? Is it equivalent to the usual squaring and eliminating radicals? I may use a computer algebra system to solve this, so it would be good to know if these methods are equivalent for solving them (I could not find any literature on that).

Comment: It looks like this system is always equivalent to the original equation. Then my question is mostly about the method with resultants. After some thought it seems that since resultants say whether a system has solutions, it should work. But a link to an article to cite would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I would write the equation in the form $$\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
with $$x\geq 1$$ after squaring one times and isolating the square root we get
$$2\sqrt{1-x^2}(1-x)=2x^2-2x-1$$ squaring again we obtain
$$(x^2-1)(2-2x)^2=(2x^2-2x-1)^2$$ this gives the equation $$4x-5=0$$ and we get $$x=\frac{5}{4}$$ fulfills our equation.
in the second equation we get $$x=1$$
write your third equation in the form
$$\sqrt{\frac{4x+1}{x+3}}=1+\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x+3}}$$ we get after squaring two times
$$\left(\frac{2x}{x+3}\right)^2-4\left(\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right)=0$$
after simplifying we obtain$$-4\,{\frac {x-6}{ \left( x+3 \right) ^{2}}}=0$$

Comment: Thanks; I'm not asking for specific answers though, I'm asking for a more general idea of how to solve similar questions.

Comment: i have read you question carefully but i think such a general procedure doesn't exist we must try to get a polynomial in $x$ which we can solve or we take a numerical method

Comment: For example, one way is replacing the roots with variables; are there are any other ways?

Comment: yes this is one way but then we get often a non linear equation system which is in the general not easy to solve

Comment: your first and third equation have a special form and are easy to solve without a trick

Comment: How do you identify and solve questions of such "special form"?

Comment: i have solved thousends of such problems in my math circle in Leipzig

Comment: Ok, but my question still stands: How do you identify and solve questions of such "special form"?