# How to solve a system of 2 unknows with radical from the Vietnamese University Entrance exam?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

I am running into a problem of solving the following system of 2 equations and 2 unknows $x,y$ over the real

$x \left(4 x^2+1\right)+(y-3) \sqrt{5-2 y}=0$
and
$4 x^2+2 \sqrt{3-4 x}+y^2-7=0$

This problem belong to the Vietnamese University Entrance exam of Block A (Math, Physic and Chemistry) in 2010

My questions are:

1/ How to solve this challenging system

a/ Exactly in a systematic way

b/ Using numerical method

2/ Is there a general way to solve system with radical like this ?

Note that the solution is $(x,y)=(\frac{1}{2} , 2)$

The link to the full exam paper is

https://toanmath.com/2015/07/de-thi-va-dap-an-mon-toan-khoi-a-nam-2010.html

Thank you for your enthusiasm

Edit: To solve this system exactly, one can follow the method dictate from this post:

[General Principles of Solving Radical Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793591/general-principles-of-solving-radical-equations)

Comment: I’m commuting so cannot solve it yet. But IMO, the answer for is no, this kind of problem doesn not have systematic way, cannot be solved by numerical method and there is no geberal way

Comment: One trick would be that you set $5-2y=3-4x$ and check if that leads to a solution.

Comment: @garondal it seems to work but what's next ?

Comment: The first equation is equivalent to $5-2y=4x^2$, with $x\ge0$, but it's not really obvious how to get there...

Comment: Using my ansatz you would get $y-1=2x$ and then you can replace every $y$ with $x$ and then get rid of the square root term. But you will still end up with $0=-4x^3+4x^2+11x-6$. So I think this is not the nicest solution.

Comment: Algebraic geometry is not an appropriate tag for this question. From the tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." Please read the tag descriptions before using them in the future.

Comment: @garondal From there, in the hope that the answer is rational, you could use the rational root theorem to find it. There are $24$ cases to check ($\pm\frac11, \pm\frac12, \ldots, \pm\frac64$), but we can eliminate almost all of them by using the constraint $0 \le x \le \frac34$. Only three cases remain: $\frac12$, $\frac14$, and $\frac34$. All of this, however, represents a lot of work based on lucky guesses...

Comment: Was this the actual question in the exam, or was this something that came out when you worked on a problem in, say, analytic geometry?

Comment: A "general" method here is to remove the square roots and get a system of two polynomial equations (knowing that squaring may introduce extra solutions). Then you can eliminate one of the variables. Gröbner basis techniques allow us to eliminate $x$ and we end up with a degree $24$ polynomial equation on $y$. That has only two real roots, $y=2$ and $y=-2$, giving points $(1/2,2)$, $(-3/2,-2)$, but the latter is a false solution (wrong sign for square root). The other 22 solutions are complex. I doubt that even in Vietnam students are taught this :-). That's why I asked the previous question.

Comment: In theory kids could be trained to spot the solution in @Théophile's comment (once you spot it, it is not hard to show that it is the only real solution for $y$ in the first equation)., but that is a bit outlandish. That's why I came up with the theory that you were working on a problem, and one approach lead to this system of equation, when another approach would give a smoother ride.

Comment: Isolating the radical in the first equation, you get a cubic in $y$ which has a factor linear in $y$ and a factor which has no real solutions. The first factor is the one Theophile found, and I agree that spotting this is a bit rough, so I wonder if Jyrki's hypothesis may be true.

Comment: If one eliminates $x$ using $3-4x=5-2y$, and then the square roots, one gets in the end $(y^2-4)(y-5)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link! So I was wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution proposed on the page you linked?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca the solution from the ministry of education follows the line of thinking "solving by knowing the answer" . This is not really fair.

Comment: To me that solution doesn't look worse than the solutions proposed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what can we say about the number of possible solutions? Well, when $y > 0$, the first curve has positive slope and the second negative. So there is at most $1$ solution with $y > 0$. Could there be a solution with $y \le 0?$ From the first equation, that would mean $x(4x^2+1) \ge 3\sqrt{5} > 5$, i.e., $x > 1$. But that would make the radical in the second equation complex, so we can't have $y \le 0$. Thus the problem has at most 1 solution, and it has positive $y$.

Let's get more bounds on the possible solutions. Going back to the first equation, we note that $y \le 5/2$ is required for the radical to be real, and as such  $(y-3)\sqrt{5-2y}$ is never positive. Therefore $x(4x^2+1)$, and hence $x$ itself, is nonnegative. And of course, from the radical in the second equation, we have $x \le 3/4$. The solution is now restricted to the interval $(x, y)\in [0, 3/4]\times(0, 5/2]$.

Now since this is an exam problem, the radicals probably can't be too "bad". They're likely to be in $\mathbb Z$, very likely to be in $\mathbb Q$, and, if it comes to it, almost certainly in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{n}]$. Starting with $\mathbb Z$, the only options consistent with the bounds are $\sqrt{4-3x} \in \{0, 1\}$ and $\sqrt{5-2y}\in \{0, 1, 2\}$. Trying all 6 possible combinations finds a solution: $(x, y) \in (1/2, 2)$.